# Testing the REST Service

Tags: json, rest

I'm working on a Rest service Where I'd Patch the incoming request. I need some help on how to test the service and with the apex class . Below is the sample snippet.

```
"request": {
        "Data": {
                   value : null,
                   SCA   : null

            "Address": [
                {
                    city : null,
                    Zip  : null,
                Country  : null 
                }
            ],
            "addressValue": null 
       }
```

Apex Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {

public class Data {
public String value;
public String SCA;
public String Addressvalue;
public List<Address> Address;
```

}

```
public class Address {
    public String City;
    public String Zip;
    public String Country;
}

@HttpPut
global static String doPatch() {
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
  // check for a opportunity with below opportunityid and opp.accountid == below accountid then perform update. 
}

}

<instancename>/accountid/contactid/opportunityid
```

is how I'm looking to make the request.

I'm trying to use some chrome plugins like DHC/rest client. But I don't know on how exactly to prepare and pass the request through the plugins to match the class.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your JSON body is not valid, use http://jsonlint.com/ before passing the request body

2) Your class is incomplete / you have not pasted complete class inyour question.

3) There are many tools thought I prefer workbench since I have been using it for a long time (personal fav)
https://workbench.developerforce.com/

**STEP 1:** Go to the above link, authenticate using your sandbox or PRD credentials.

**STEP 2:** From the tabs at the top pick "REST EXPLORER" from the "Utilities" drop down.

**STEP 3:** Pick "PUT"as your http method and paste 
(If I were you I would give the url mapping a proper version and give it a proper endpoint name, something like @RestResource(urlMapping='/v1.0/myuri'))

paste `/services/apexrest/*` in the text box before the execute button and paste the request body and hit execute.

you should be able to see pretty/ raw response.
My example class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource1 {

@HttpPut
global static String doPatch() {
return 'hello';
}

}
```

Workbench screen:
[image]